# Summarize "Character" information within a data frame in R similar to Excel Pivot without Duplicates and Numbers

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to get the same function as an Excel pivot in R. I have a huge data set, but it shows the unique values without repetitions and only for text as shown below.

I tried to use `summarise()` and `reframe()` but I am not getting the desirable solution.

The code I wrote is given below:

```r
library(readxl)
    Book1 <- read_excel("C:/Users/X/X- X X/Desktop/Book1.xlsx")

X <- Book1 %>%
      reframe(Country,Group,Name)
```

Attached is the data frame I am working with:

```r
structure(list(Country = c("France", "France", "France", "France", 
    "France", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany"
    ), Group = c("Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
    "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male"), Name = c("Grace", "Steph", 
    "Tiff", "John", "John", "Luca", "Andre", "Reus", "Alica", "Reus"
    ), Age = c(33, 34, 33, 22, 22, 20, 25, 29, 29, 29)), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

This is the expected output as the output which I would get from an Excel pivot:

https://imgur.com/a/KYLeyXu

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and how to correct it? Apologies for showing the image, but I felt this would be easier to understand.

Comment: Where are you putting this and what is your goal with it? In R, data frames are rectangular - every column has the same number of rows, and blanks are usually to be avoided. If you'd like you could change all the duplicates to blanks "by group" to make it look more like your pivot table screenshot, but that will make modeling or plotting the data very difficult. On the other hand if you are creating a table for a document, you will probably need special purpose functions depending on what sort of document you are creating, maybe HTML, PDF, or Word.

Comment: @GregorThomas I dont mind if the items in the rows are repeated. I have updated the image for output. It Can you have a look now and update the answer?

Comment: Are you just looking for: `X %>% arrange(Country, Group, Name)`?

Comment: Now that the rows are repeated in your picture, the `dput` data that you put in the question looks like your picture. I don't understand how what you have is different from what you want.

Comment: @GregorThomas Good Catch, I had taken dput of a subset. I have corrected it.

Comment: `unique(xyzzy[-4L])`? Where `xyzzy` is your data and `4L` corresponds to the `Age`-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is relatively simple, all you need is distinct items.

```r
library(dplyr)

X <- Book1 %>%
      distinct(Country,Group,Name)
```

The output is:

```
  Country Group  Name 
  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>
1 France  Female Grace
2 France  Female Steph
3 France  Female Tiff 
4 France  Male   John 
5 Germany Male   Luca 
6 Germany Male   Andre
7 Germany Male   Reus 
8 Germany Female Alica
```